# Short story compilation where living could see dead after taking a drug

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story sci fi/horror compilation.

One of the stories was where a chemical had been released from a lab which meant the living could see the (not very pleasant) dead. I think it was 'thirteen tales .....l.'  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you remember whether there were sci-fi stories that were not horror? Also, what is the "I" at the end of the title?

Comment: http://yarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/thirteen-little-taste-of-death-patricia.html? - Originally collected in http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1003291.Thirteen_Tales_of_Horror

Comment: Maybe something in [here](https://www.amazon.com/Wrapped-White-Thirteen-Spectres-Spirits-ebook/dp/B00J7A0RJS#nav-subnav)?

Comment: None of these I'm afraid - the book had a lot more sci fi in it than these.  The chemical in question was released from a lab via the water supply, and the survivors had the only non- polluted source.